# Cross-correlation of two 1D tensors

Tags: pytorch, padding, shapes, tensor, cross-correlation

I have my input signal shape = (N,) and my kernel Shape = (K,). I think both should be of same size in order for me to get a cross-correlated output between input signal and my kernel. Is there any way I could use zero padding on my input signal to achieve the result?

For example: Cross correlation between input signal (1,2,3,4,5) and kernel (6,7).

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I'm wrong but this seems to correspond to a 1D convolution:

NumPy has a builtin, [`np.correlate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html), we can compare to:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 6)
>>> v = np.arange(6, 8)

>>> np.correlate(a, v)
array([20, 33, 46, 59])
```

And in PyTorch with [`torch.nn.functional.conv1d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/generated/torch.nn.functional.conv1d.html) (the input and weight need to be three-dimensional):

```
>>> x = torch.tensor(a, dtype=float)[None, None]
>>> w = torch.tensor(v, dtype=float)[None, None]

>>> F.conv1d(x, w)
tensor([[[20., 33., 46., 59.]]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Comment: I have the following sizes
Input signal: torch.Size([200])
Kernel: torch.Size([18])
Output: torch.Size([183])
How do I make the size of my output equal to input?

Comment: You have `#a + p - #v + 1= #out`, where `p` is the padding amount, so `p = #out - #a + #v - 1`. Knowing `#a = #out`, you have `p = #v - 1`. You should therefore pad `a` with `#v - 1` elements.

Comment: @Ivan yes, PyTorch's `Conv1d` is exactly equivalent to cross correlation as mentioned by [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html): `where ⋆ is the valid cross-correlation operator [...]`.